# How to retrive data from python function and use it in a emr operator

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, mwaa

Airflow version :2.0.2
Trying to create Emr cluster, by retrying data from AWS secrets manager.

I am trying to write an airflow dag and, my task is to get data from  this get_secret function and use it in Spark_steps

```
def get_secret():
    secret_name =  Variable.get("secret_name")
    region_name = Variable.get(region_name)
    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name=region_name)
    account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
    
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret_str = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            secret=json.loads(secret_str)            
            airflow_path=secret["airflow_path"]
            return  airflow_path
```

...
I need to use "airflow_path" return value  in below spark_steps
Spark_steps:

```
SPARK_STEPS = [

    {
        'Name': 'Spark-Submit Command',
        "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
                'spark-submit',
                '--py-files',
                's3://'+airflow_path+'-pyspark/pitchbook/config.zip,s3://'+airflow_path+'-pyspark/pitchbook/jobs.zip,s3://'+airflow_path+'-pyspark/pitchbook/DDL.zip',
                's3://'+airflow_path+'-pyspark/pitchbook/main.py'
                    ],
                        },
    },
```

I saw on the internet I need to use Xcom, is this right ?, and do I need to run this function in python operator first and then get the value. please provide an example as I am a newbie.

Thanks for your help.
Xi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you would like to pass dynamic stuff, leveraging xcom push/pull might be easier.

Leverage [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html) to push data into xcom.

See reference implementation:

 https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7fed7f31c3a895c0df08228541f955efb16fbf79/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_emr.py

 https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7fed7f31c3a895c0df08228541f955efb16fbf79/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_emr.py#L108

https://www.startdataengineering.com/post/how-to-submit-spark-jobs-to-emr-cluster-from-airflow/